# How can I wait until the previous method returns OK before running the next method in AngularJS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devise, oauth-2.0

In my signUp method, I fetch a API token for the user, then I redirect him to a different page.
How can I postpone the redirection until I have received the token? The URL that I want to redirect to is in `data.url`.

```
  $scope.signIn = () ->    
    $http(
      # Perform a regular Devise login
      method: "POST"
      url: "/users/sign_in"
      data: authData
    ).success (data) ->
       getUserToken($scope.email, $scope.password)
       $scope.current_user = data.user
       # Redirect to URL
       # The redirection needs to wait for the getUserToken.
       $window.location = data.url



  getUserToken = (username, password) ->
    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: "/oauth/token"
      params: params
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.$storage.token = data.access_token
```

**Refactored code**

```
getUserToken = (username, password) ->
  console.log "I'm first"
  $http(
    method: "POST"
    url: "/oauth/token"
    params: params
  ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
    $scope.$storage.token = data.access_token

    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = \
      "Bearer #{data.access_token}"
  )


defer = $q.defer()

$scope.signIn = (data) ->
  defer.promise
    .then( getUserToken($scope.email, $scope.password) )
    .then( deviseLogin() )
    .then( redirect(url) )  # redirect() is never executed.


redirect = (url) ->
  console.log "I'm last"
  console.log "will redirect to #{url}"
  $window.location = data.url

deviseLogin = () ->
  console.log "I'm second"
  authData = { user: { email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password }}

  $http(
    # Perform a regular Devise login
    method: "POST"
    url: "/users/sign_in"
    data: authData
  )
  .success (data) ->
    console.log "logged in with Devise"
    console.log "data.url: #{data.url}"
    return data.url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the redirection statement in the success block of the function that fetches the user token..

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to not mix the redirect logic into the getUserToken method.

Comment: declare $scope.redirect = function() {} and write the redirection logic inside this method.. Next in your getUserToken method, pass $scope.redirect as a parameter.. When your getUserToken method succeeds, call the variable pointed that holds the method reference..

Comment: I never got the last `.then( redirect(url) )` to kick in. Solved the problem by moving `redirect(url)` to within success() on `deviseLogin()`.

Thanks for all the suggestions and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function of redirection, as follow:

```
$scope.signIn = () ->    
    $http(
      # Perform a regular Devise login
      method: "POST"
      url: "/users/sign_in"
      data: authData
    ).success (data) ->
       $scope.current_user = data.user
       getUserToken($scope.email, $scope.password) ->
         # Redirect to URL
         # The redirection needs to wait for the getUserToken.
         $window.location = data.url



  getUserToken = (username, password, redirection) ->
    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: "/oauth/token"
      params: params
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.$storage.token = data.access_token
      redirection()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.signIn = () ->    
    $http(
      # Perform a regular Devise login
      method: "POST"
      url: "/users/sign_in"
      data: authData
    ).success (data) ->
       getUserToken($scope.email, $scope.password)



  getUserToken = (username, password) ->
    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: "/oauth/token"
      params: params
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.$storage.token = data.access_token   


    //just move that bit to success getUserToken calback


         $scope.current_user = data.user
       # Redirect to URL
       # The redirection needs to wait for the getUserToken.
       $window.location = data.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making it asynchronous just like in ajax.
$http(
    method: "POST"
 
    url: "/oauth/token"
 
    params: params
 
    **async:   false**
);